# perl -a: How to change column separator?

Tags: perl, command-line, record

I want to read the columns in a file where the separator is `:`.

I tried it like this (because according to http://www.asciitable.com, the octal representation of the colon is 072):

```
$ echo "a:b:c"  | perl -a -072 -ne 'print "$F[1]\n";'
```

I want it to print `b`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at `-F` in perlrun:

```
% echo "a:b:c" | perl -a -F: -ne 'print "$F[1]\n";'
b
```

Note that the value is taken as regular expression, so some delimiters may need some extra escaping:

```
% echo "a.b.c" | perl -a -F. -ne 'print "$F[1]\n";'

% echo "a.b.c" | perl -a -F\\. -ne 'print "$F[1]\n";'
b
```

Comment: `-0` sets the *record separator* (Perl's notion of what separates one line from the next)

Comment: It's the record separator, not the field separator.

Comment: @Frank, `-0` specifies the record (line) separator (whereas `-F` specifies the input field separator). Added details to my answer.

Comment: As an FYI, `-F` is inherited from `awk`.

Comment: Note that the separator is taken as regular expression, so for period (`a.b.c`) you need to say `perl -a -F\\.`

Comment: Thx for mentioning the "regex expression" part of it.  I am wondering how to specify a space (only a space). The -F\\s works for *any* whitespace but not for *just* space

Answer (score 5):

`-0` specifies the *record* (line) separator. It was cause Perl to receive three lines:

```
>echo a:b:c | perl -072 -nE"say"
a:
b:
c
```

Since there's no whitespace on any of those lines, `$F[1]` would be empty if `-a` were to be used.

`-F` specifies the input *field* separator. This is what you want.

```
perl -F: -lanE'say $F[1];'
```

Or if you're stuck with an older Perl:

```
perl -F: -lane'print $F[1];'
```

Command line options are documented in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).